# Using get set methods dynamically

Tags: typescript, types

My Class :

```js
export class User {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }

    setName(name: string): void {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getAge(): number{
        return this.age;
    }

    setAge(age: number): void {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to use set and get methods dynamically, Example;

```js
User user = new User();
user.setMethod('name', 'John');  // 'name' or 'setName' (string value)
const exampleName = user.getMethod('name')  // 'name' or 'getName' (string value)
```

Is this possible with angular? Thank you...

Comment: why would you want that? there's `get` and `set` if you want property methods.

Comment: The use of Angular does not affect the basic syntax and semantics of JavaScript.

Comment: It's really very unclear to me what (or for that matter why) you want this?

Comment: `User user = new User();` -- That's not a valid TS statement.

Comment: MarkusDresch, Liam this is only an example.I have a class with 40 parameters and I check the incoming data with 40 parameters one by one.But with this method, only one line.

Comment: 31piy only example.you understand code I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have types you will have to add generic typings, but it will also list the getter/setter method.

```
export class User {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    getMethod<K extends keyof this>(key: K): this[K]{
        return this[key];
    }

    setMethod<K extends keyof this>(key: K, value: this[K]): void {
        this[key] = value;
    }
}

new User().getMethod('age') // number
new User().setMethod('age', 5) // ok
new User().setMethod('age', '5') // error
```

Comment: Akxe, can you help me?. I can't send dynamic value to methods.
For example: const exampleString: string = 'age';  new User().getMethod(exampleString); This give error

Comment: Of course, `string` is not the same as `'age' | 'name'`. If you would not specify `exampleString`'s type as `string` but as `'age'` or nothing (infer the type from value), it will work. If you need it because of other functions you will need to understand typescript generic first, but this is beyond this question.